# Input Styling Only working for type="text"

Tags: html, css

When all of my inputs are set to "text" it works beautifully.

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/beckah/62oozn3t/

However when I have additional HTML5 input elements, such as `tel` or `email`, my label refuses to float after typing in the field and than making another field active. To test, type in the "email" input and then select another input and type. you'll see that the label doesn't continue to float once not active

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/beckah/8zpd5n46/1/

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Both examples work in my browser (Chrome)

Comment: @sub6resources type in the "email" input and then select another input and type. you'll see that the label doesn't continue to float once not active. thanks for pointing this out btw!

Comment: Okay, I tried typing. The `tel` stayed up, but the `email` did collapse. I'll check your code more closely right now.

Comment: one thing I just noticed while testing is that when you enter a valid email, the email box doesn't collapse, it only collapses when an invalid email is entered.

Comment: Also another thing I noticed is that if you remove `required` from the email input, it isn't collapsed by default, and collapses after you enter an invalid email.

Comment: You're targeting your styles using `:valid` and expecting a specific style when the input is actually invalid.... (i.e here:`input.question:focus,
input.question:valid {
  padding-top: 35px;
}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your issue is with the `:valid` selector on your css in this section of code, as well as a few other places.

```
input.question:focus,
input.question:valid {
  padding-top: 35px;
}
```

Because you are using the `:valid` selector, and your email or telephone in some cases is not a valid, it collapses, whereas with your text inputs, as long as it is not empty, it will not collapse again.

If you don't want to go through all the hassle of writing JavaScript, you can make it a normal text input and it won't have the `@` and `.com` keys available on mobile, but it will work as designed.

To fix this fully, you should check the `input` via JavaScript, as there is no way in CSS to see if a `textarea` or `input` has text inside. You can do this by basically checking to see if the `value` of the input is not empty, and if it isn't, adjust the css style via javascript with `getElementById().style.padding = "35px";`

I'm sorry there is no simple solution, but CSS doesn't have anything for inputs like this yet.